# The service "sonata.formatter.form.type.selector" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_ck_editor.config_manager"

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, fckeditor

I need to use SonataFormatterBundle but after updating composer I get this error:

> The service "sonata.formatter.form.type.selector" has a dependency on
>   a non-existent service "fos_ck_editor.config_manager".

My AppKrenel.php

```
<?php

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),

            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            // These are the other bundles the SonataAdminBundle relies on
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

            // And finally, the storage and SonataAdminBundle
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),

            new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
            new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
            new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
            //new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
            new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),

            new Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle(),

            new CoopTilleuls\Bundle\AclSonataAdminExtensionBundle\CoopTilleulsAclSonataAdminExtensionBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),

            //new Sonata\DashboardBundle\SonataDashboardBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),
#            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
            new Sonata\FormatterBundle\SonataFormatterBundle(),
            new Sonata\TranslationBundle\SonataTranslationBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
            new Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle(),
            new RedCode\TreeBundle\RedCodeTreeBundle(),
            //new ImportacioBundle\ImportacioBundle(),
            new FrontBundle\FrontBundle(),
            new FOS\CKEditorBundle\FOSCKEditorBundle(),

        ];


}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "oriol/multiweb",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
            "ImportacioBundle\\": "src/ImportacioBundle",
            "FrontBundle\\": "src/FrontBundle",
            "Application\\": "src/Application"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "~1.1",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.8",
        "redcode/tree-bundle": "0.1-alpha",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.16",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.3",
        "sonata-project/dashboard-bundle": "^0.1.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.2",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "~3.2",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.5",
        "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.2",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "^3.4",
        "tilleuls/acl-sonata-admin-extension-bundle": "^2.0",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }


}
```

I can update composer but, after clearing cache I get this error.

Some time ago, it worked and I was using ivory fckeditor and symfony 3.3. But after update composer something changed and fck don't work. Now, i neither knows how come back to last version I had in composer.